# p:ajax for p:selectOneMenu not invoking backend method (listener)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am trying to render an input box based on the value selected in the drop down.

I had placed the input box under a panelGrid as below

```
                        <h:panelGrid id="pnl1" styleClass="Container90"
                            columnClasses="Wid20, Wid80" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                            <p:outputLabel for="clientRegAcessToken1"
                                value="Client Registration Token"
                                rendered="#{clientRegistration.regSecretShown}" />
                            <p:inputText id="clientRegAcessToken1"
                                rendered="#{clientRegistration.regSecretShown}"
                                value="#{clientRegistration.regToken}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
```

I have the selectOneMenu as below

```
                                <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="w250"
                                    id="idTokenSignedResponseAlg" 
                                    value="#{clientRegistration.client.idTokenSignedResponseAlg}" 
                                    >
                                    <f:selectItems
                                        value="#{clientRegistration.getJwsAlgorithms()}" var="algo"
                                        itemValue="#{algo}" itemLabel="#{algo.name}" />
                                    <p:ajax update="ViewClientRegistration:pnl1"
                                        listener="#{clientRegistration.onHmacSigningKeySelected}"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Method definition in the bean (ViewScoped) is as below

```
public void onHmacSigningKeySelected(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Entered" + client.getIdTokenSignedResponseAlg());
        regSecretShown=true;
    }
```

I see that changing the value is sending a network request. However, I am not seeing the method getting executed on the server side. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Did you exclude all of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked? Are you absolutely sure that it isn't just a conversion or validation error? (which is normally displayed in a messages component and otherwise logged in server log)

Comment: @BalusC, Do you see any specific point in the list applicable for me ? I don't think it applies to me. My issues is that server side method is not getting invoked.

Comment: That is where the whole Q/A BalusC referred to is about!!!. Find out yourself which one is applicable

Comment: I did go through it and it helped me earlier. But I don't think this issue is due to any of the points mentioned in the link.

Comment: So, you added a `<p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>`, but you didn't see any messages? You did nowhere explicitly exclude that.

Comment: Yes. I have <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="true"/> at the top of my page. I don't see any conversion/validation errors. Indeed I see a 200 OK response returned from the server after the value is changes for the p:selectOneMenu. My concern is the onHmacSigningKeySelected() method in the server is not getting invoked after changing the values. Looks like I am missing something else..

Comment: @BausC, I've figured out the cause. Its because the idTokenSignedResponseAlg element is under a panel that gets rendered based on a boolean value tied to the backend. As per point #5 from the link above, the rendered attribute evaluates to false and method doesn't get invoked. Now, passing the params via ajax call as <p:ajax update="ViewClientRegistration:pnl1" listener="#{clientRegistration.onHmacSigningKeySelected}">
<f:param name="showAll" value="#{clientRegistration.showAll}" />
</p:ajax> but no luck. Is there some other way to pass a params so I can parse it through request parameters